# Extract int from Decimal('6')

Tags: python

I made a SQL Select that will return me something, including a number.. But it appears like so:

```
Decimal('6')
```

How do I retrieve the number 6 from that field? 
I will also add a screenshot of this Decimal object to help you understanding what I'm looking at.

[image: Decimal object]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it to `int`.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('6')
Decimal('6')
>>> int(Decimal('6'))
6
```

Comment: did the trick, i will accept as answer in 5 minutes! but i already tried using int before, and i dont know why it didnt work haha

Answer (score 3):

you can `int()` it, and then you will have the number as an integer:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

n = Decimal("123")
print(n, type(n))
n = int(n)
print(n, type(n))
```

And the results are:

```py
123 <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
123 <class 'int'>
```